# Множество задача, не получается вывести в новое множество

Tags: python

```
"""По условию к вам в день приходит всего 10 клиентов,
при этом они могут повторяться


(то есть, один и тот же человек может за   день придти 2 раза).`

Всех пришедших пользователей нужно правильно приветствовать.
Для каждого пришедшего пользователя нужно ввести его имя (через input).

Если он уже приходил сегодня, то нужно вывести слова : "Рады снова вас видеть, ..!",
где вместо двух точек нужно написать имя пользователя.

Если он пришел первый раз, то нужно сказать: "Спасибо, что выбрали именно нас!"
При решении этой задачи желательно пользоваться  (set, while, for, if, else).

Ответ на выходе примерно такой : {'OLIVER', 'OLIVER', 'JACK', 'HARRY', 'JACOB',
         'CHARLIE', 'JESSICA', 'JESSICA', 'OSCAR',
         'SOPHIE', 'JAMES', 'GEORGE', GEORGE'}
"""

users = {'OLIVER', 'JACK', 'HARRY', 'JACOB',  # всего 10 клиентов, создаем множество с имена посетителей
         'CHARLIE', 'JESSICA', 'OSCAR',
         'SOPHIE', 'JAMES', 'GEORGE'}

# a = set()   создание множества
for i in range(users):
    print("Введите посетителя : ", end="")
    s = input()
    if s in users:
        a.add(s)
        print("Рады снова вас видеть, {}!".format(s))

    else:
        print("Спасибо, что выбрали именно нас!")
        a.add(s)
print(a)
```

Comment: Ожидаемого ответа на выходе быть не может, потому как одинаковых элементов в множестве не может быть по определению

Comment: У Вас множество `a` взялось из ниоткуда. Точнее Вы закоментировали строку, где создаете его. Посему код работать не будет. + `for i in range(len(users)):` или  `for i in users:` а не `for i in range(users):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну в общем как-то так получилось. Поскольку задача теоретическая, позволил себе изменить вывод:

```
from collections import Counter
users = {'OLIVER', 'JACK', 'HARRY', 'JACOB',  # всего 10 клиентов, создаем множество с имена посетителей
         'CHARLIE', 'JESSICA', 'OSCAR',
         'SOPHIE', 'JAMES', 'GEORGE'}


def times(c: int):  # Правильно склоняем слово раз
    if c in [2, 3, 4]:
        return 'раза'
    if c in [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]:
        return 'раз'


a = []   # создание списка сегодняшних посетителей
for _ in range(10):  # регистрируем 10 посетителей
    s = input("Введите имя посетителя : ").upper()  # Приветствие для ввода можно указать так
    if s in users or s in a:  # Если чел наш постоянный клиент (сответсвенно добавлен в список ПОСТОЯННЫХ посетителей
                            # либо в список заходивших сегодня
        print("Рады снова вас видеть, {}!".format(s))  # Приветствуем его так
    else:  # Если он у нас в первый раз
        print("Спасибо, что выбрали именно нас, {}".format(s))  # Приветствуем по другому
    a.append(s)  # и добавляем в список сегодняшних посетителей

# Выводим результат за день через Counter
# Функция преобразует список в словарь с элементами списка ввиде ключей (не повторяются соответсвенно)
# И количеством вхождений в список для каждого элемента ввиде значения соответственно
print("Сегодня:")
for name, count in Counter(a).items(): # Получаем пару ключ - значение для каждого посетителя
    # и присваиваем из значения переменным
    print('{} посетил нас {} {}.'.format(name, count, times(count)))  # Выводим соответствующую информацию
```

Answer (score 2):

```
users = set()

while len(users) < 10:
    user = input("Введите посетителя: ")
    if user not in users:
        print("Спасибо, что выбрали именно нас!")
        users.add(user)
    else:
        print("Рады снова вас видеть, {}!".format(user))
```

---

*Обьяснение:*

Ваша программа почти хорошая - возможно убрать команду

```
users = {'OLIVER', 'JACK', 'HARRY', 'JACOB',  # всего 10 клиентов, создаем множество с имена посетителей
     'CHARLIE', 'JESSICA', 'OSCAR',
     'SOPHIE', 'JAMES', 'GEORGE'}
```

т.к. клиенты будут вводится интерактивно; команда

```
a = set()   #создание множества
```

нужна, т.к. начинаем день пустым множеством; вместо двух строк

```
    print("Введите посетителя : ", end="")
    s = input()
```

возможно писать только одну

```
    s = input("Введите посетителя : ")
```

и использовать лучшие имена для переменных.

Comment: А Вас не смутило то, что автор вопроса предполагает вывод в виде  `{'OLIVER', 'OLIVER', 'JACK', 'HARRY', 'JACOB',
         'CHARLIE', 'JESSICA', 'JESSICA', 'OSCAR',
         'SOPHIE', 'JAMES', 'GEORGE', GEORGE'}`?

Comment: @Andrey, это не вывод, и пример *ввода* (ошибка в задании, как ясно вытекает из контекста).

Comment: на самом деле Andrey прав примерный вывод ввиде множества

Answer (score 1):

```
# Оборачиваем в функцию и добавляем условие с возможностью выхода из цикла после вопроса.
# Но тут не добавляются одинаковые множества(одинаковые посетители),
#  потомучто во множестве можетбыть один одинаковый элемент.

def new_visitor(visit):
    """Функция принимающее любое множество, запись новых посетителей в новое множество """
    incoming_visitor = set()                                   # создание нового список множества
    for i in range(len(visit)):                   # где len(visit) это количество элементов во множестве
        name = input("Еще придут посетители ? :")

        # Добавляем условие if с возможностью выхода из цикла в тот момент когда спрашивают пользователя.
        if name == 'Нет' or name == 'НЕТ':
            break
        visitor_entry = input("Введите нового посетителя : ")# Введите имя  посетителя


        if visitor_entry in visit:                  # Если введеной посетитель уже есть во множестве
            incoming_visitor.add(visitor_entry)             # Добавляем во множество
            print("Рады снова вас видеть, {}!".format(visitor_entry))  # Вывод приветствия через метод формат
            print("Текущий список посетителей, {}!".format(incoming_visitor)) # Вывод приветствия через метод формат



        else:
            print("Спасибо, что выбрали именно нас и снова зашли!")# Вывод приветствия через метод формат
            incoming_visitor.add(visitor_entry)      # Добавляем во множество
            print("Текущий список посетителей, {}!".format(incoming_visitor)) # Вывод приветствия через метод формат
    print("Общий журнал посетителей, {}!".format(incoming_visitor))  # Вывод приветствия через метод формат
```